# pystackexchange polling issue

Tags: python, stackexchange

So, I'm fairly new to python and I had an idea today to make a script that polls stackoverflow for my rep, and when it changes, it sends an email, which gets sent to my phone as a text.

The emailing part works, but for some reason I can't get the polling right, so I decided I'd see if maybe you guys wanted to take a stab at it.

Here's my code:

```
import sys
from stackauth import StackAuth
from stackexchange import Site, StackOverflow
import smtplib

from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email import Encoders
import os

import time

gmail_user = "email@gmail.com"
gmail_pwd = "password"

def mail(to, subject, text):
   msg = MIMEMultipart()

   msg['From'] = gmail_user
   msg['To'] = to
   msg['Subject'] = subject

   msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

   mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
   mailServer.ehlo()
   mailServer.starttls()
   mailServer.ehlo()
   mailServer.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
   mailServer.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg.as_string())
   # Should be mailServer.quit(), but that crashes...
   mailServer.close()

old_rep = None

while True:

    user_id = 731221 if len(sys.argv) < 2 else int(sys.argv[1])
    print 'StackOverflow user %d\'s accounts:' % user_id

    stack_auth = StackAuth()
    so = Site(StackOverflow)
        accounts = stack_auth.associated(so, user_id)
    REP =  accounts[3].reputation
    print REP
        if REP != old_rep:
        old_rep = REP
                mail("email@email.com","REP",str(REP))
    time.sleep(10)
```

Currently if you print REP it is right at first, but doesnt update if my rep changes. 
Ideally it would. 
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: damn formatting, I'll fix it, bare with me. Sorry.

Comment: There are seem to be some indentation errors, you should fix your code in the while loop. When you say the polling doesn't work right, what do you expect it to do, what is the current behavior?

Comment: i don't think there are any indentation errors in the actual code, I'm not used to stackoverflows formatting. 
Currently if you print REP it is right at first, but doesnt update if my rep changes. 
Ideally it would.

Comment: You should fix the indentation errors in your post so people will be more inclined to help.

Comment: I'm working on it. Sorry. Is there an easier way to paste code? I'm typing four spaces on every line, this seems silly.

Comment: You can use the {} code format button on selections of text to indent it properly all at once.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplified example that will loop properly:

```
import time
from stackauth import StackAuth
from stackexchange import Site, StackOverflow

rep = None
while True:
    stack_auth = StackAuth()
    so = Site(StackOverflow)
    accounts = stack_auth.associated(so, 641766) # using my id
    so_acct = filter(lambda x: x.on_site.api_endpoint.endswith('api.stackoverflow.com'), accounts)[0] # filtering my accounts so I only check rep on stackoverflow
    if rep != so_acct.reputation:
        rep = so_acct.reputation
        print rep
        # send e-mail
    time.sleep(30)
```

I added a line to filter the accounts so it will only check your rep on the proper site. You were using the index, I have no idea if that's stable or not, I'd guess not. Polling every 10 seconds (like in the original example) might be a bit much, maybe do something more reasonable like every 5 minutes? Do you really need an up to the minute update of your rep? Consider just writing this as a cron job and having it run every 5, 10, 15 minutes whatever.

Comment: This doesnt work either, try it for yourself. And make sure you test what it does when your rep changes. :D